# Trouble while installing truffle-contract module

Tags: truffle

When I run the command `sudo npm install truffle-contract` it gives me this error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone -q https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git /home/ubuntu/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-777489e7
npm ERR! /home/ubuntu/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-777489e7/.git: Permission denied
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2017-12-26T05_11_27_119Z-debug.log
```

Comment: @askshat did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. Works if you remove `sudo` from your install command.